# ordering rows in table with custom order each row unique mysql

Tags: mysql

The user who is an instructor should be able to add courses, and each course has chapters and each chapter should have a specific order.

In other words, when the instructor wants to add a chapter, he should be able to choose the order of these chapters among all the chapters.. and the same thing for updating the chapter.

how can I do this in MySQL?

`UPDATE TABLE table SET ID += 1 WHERE ID>=9;INSERT INTO TABLE(ID,...) VALUES(9,..)`
I have seen something like this but I don't want to affect the ids in the database

Comment: You need to add a new column: `SortOrder`. Generally speaking, your primary-key values should be immutable (so never do `UPDATE SET ID = ...`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, your question does not provide enough information for someone unfamiliar with your tables and problem.  Please provide information about the tables involved, sample input and sample desired output.  Also, please indicate what you've tried and the results of those attempts.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I have the following tables: majors(id, name... )  and courses(id, major_id, name...) and an administration panel allowing a user of role instructor to insert the latter. But I want to add a functionality that the instructor should be able to reorder the lessons and thats the point of my question. Can you supply me with a logic for this knowing that I am using mysql database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MahmoudJoumaa I *already told you* in my comment reply. **You need to add a new column to the table** to store the sort-order information.